# Which row exchanges will produce another Sudoku matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutation-matrices, sudoku

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang**

A $9$ by $9$ Sudoku matrix $S$ has the numbers $1,...,9$ in every row and column and in every $3$ by $3$ block. For the all-ones vector $\overrightarrow { x }  = (1,...,1),$ what is $S\overrightarrow { x } $?

A better question is: Which row exchanges will produce another Sudoku matrix? Also, which exchanges of block rows give another Sudoko matrix?

$6$ orders for the first $3$ rows can be seen, all giving Sudoku matrices. Also, $6$ permutations of the next $3$ rows, and of the last $4$ rows. And $6$ block permutations of the block rows?

---

What I understand:

The first part is pretty simple for me to understand. Without even constructing matrix $S$, it's obvious that $S\overrightarrow { x } $ will be:

$\left[\begin{array}{r}
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
    45  \\
  \end{array}\right]$

since the numbers $(1,...,9)$ added up will always be $45$.

What I don't understand:

What does the author mean by "Which row exchanges will produce another Sudoku matrix?" I want an explanation that will help me solve the last parts of this question on my own?

Comment: Let's suppose we swap 2 rows. How can we swap 2 rows while preserving the Sudoku matrix property?

Comment: @Element118 Well, every single row, column, and $3$ by $3$ block would still have to have the numbers $1,...,9$, but I don't know how to maintain that if we swap two rows..

Comment: Can you construct some Sudoku matrix and try a some swap of 2 rows?

Comment: Sure, I'll use a $3$ by $3$ sudoku matrix that I used before. The first row had $(8,3,4)$. The second row had $(1,5,9)$. The third row had $(6,7,2)$.
I can swap the first and second rows, but this is no longer a sudoku matrix...

Comment: I think they referred to a 9-by-9 matrix...

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you meant *any* sudoku matrix. Here is a $9$ by $9$ sudoku matrix: $$\pmatrix {9&8&3&4&5&2&7&1&6\\4&5&2&7&1&6&9&8&3\\7&1&6&9&8&3&4&5&2\\8&3&4&5&2&7&1&6&9\\5&2&7&1‌​&6&9&8&3&4\\1&6&9&8&3&4&5&2&7\\3&4&5&2&7&1&6&9&8\\2&7&1&6&9&8&3&4&5\\6&9&8&3&4&5&2&7&‌​1}$$

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for here? In general, the answer is a function of the exact matrix.

Comment: @ASimmons To be honest, it's a bit unclear to me what exact answer is being sought out here by the author. I just don't understand how I can figure out which row exchanges would produce another sudoku matrix other than by trial and error right now.

Comment: There are some row exchanges that will, for any sudoku grid, produce another valid sudoku grid. There are some that will produce a valid grid only for specific starting grids. I think the author probably expects you to find the former.

Comment: So, I need to find a row exchange that will produce another Sudoku matrix and row exchanges within blocks that will give another Sudoku matrix?

How would I do this in a systematic way? Or are you saying that trial and error is the way to go right now?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is given in [18.06 problem set solutions](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring14/ps1_s14_sol.pdf) (page 3). Excerpt from there

**Solution:** For a Sudoku matrix $S$, and $x = (1, 1, ..., 1)$, $Sx$ is a column
vector with 9 elements, all equal to 45:

$$Sx = (45, 45, ...45) = 45 \cdot x$$

There are 6 permutations of three numbers: $(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1),
(3,1,2) and (3,2,1)$ as mentioned in Section 2.7. Group each three rows, i.e.
row 1-3, 4-6 and 7-9, and we can do row permutations inside each group,
which would still give us Sudoku matrix. This in total gives $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$ ways of creating new (Sudoku) matrices.

And exchange the order of the three row blocks will also give us Sudoku
matrix. This gives another 6 ways of permutation. Combined with the
row permutation inside each group, in total, we have $6^4 = 1296$ orders of
9 rows that stay Sudoku.